# How to create C# classes to deserialize a JSON string which starts and ends with square brackets

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am receiving a JSON string back from an API and want to deserialize it into C# objects but cannot get the classes correct.

I have tried creating the classes using http://json2csharp.com/ but it can't parse the JSON, however https://jsonlint.com/ says that the JSON is valid.

I also tried running [JsonClassGeneratorLib](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=jsonclassgenerator) but that says

> Unable to cast object of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

It seems to be an issue because the JSON is enclosed in `[]` square brackets. I believe this is valid but makes it into an array. I think I need an array somewhere in my class.

```
string Json = @"[""error"",{""code"":2,""msg"":""This API Key is invalid""}]";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Json);


public class CodeMsg
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public long Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("msg")]
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string String { get; set; }
    public CodeMsg cm { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

I always get the error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsoleApp1.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like `List<T>` that can be deserialized from a JSON array

Comment: Can't do much better than quoting the error message: `change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is a heterogeneous array containing a string and an object.  This will not deserialize cleanly into a strongly-typed class structure without a little help. One possible solution is to use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) like this:

```
public class ResultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Result);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        Result result = new Result
        {
            String = array[0].Value<string>(),
            cm = array[1].ToObject<CodeMsg>(serializer)
        };
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then tie the converter to your `Result` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResultConverter))]
public class Result
{
    public string String { get; set; }
    public CodeMsg cm { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, deserialize the JSON into the `Result` class like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(Json);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RLpm5W

Note: You can delete the `RootObject` class; it is not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>(Json);
```

Explanation: If the JSON is an Array, the C# RootObject has to be either deriving from List/IEnumerable itself, or you deserialize it to a List/Array of the Type.

You can dump your `RootObject` class. If you wanted to use the `RootObject` type, make it derive from List. But this is not worth the hassle.

Comment: That then gives me this `Error converting value "error" to type 'ConsoleApp1.Result'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 8.`

Comment: Can you enclose your `Result` type in brackets so it is interpreted as a coherent object? `@"[ {""error"",{""code"":2,""msg"":""This API Key is invalid""}}]";`

Comment: I just realized what you're expressing is a or type (I think you can call it discriminated union): it's either the string "error", or the object "CodeMsg". You can't really express that in C#. Hence my recommendation with the object syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure, your json string must have same properties as JsonHolder class.

```
public class JsonHolder
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Gender {get;set;}
}

var jsonHolderList = new JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonHolder>>(jsonString);
var jsonHolder = jsonHolderList.Single()
```

You can also convert json string into c# object as dynamic object. Just make sure, your json string must have same properties as JsonHolder class.

```
dynamic obj= new JsonConver.DeserializeObject<List<JsonHolder>>(StrJson);
```

Comment: Just make sure, your json string must have same properties as JsonHolder class.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. I moved your comment to body - please delete your comment (I can't).